# How to embed ContextualWeb News API in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am trying to embed ContextualWeb News API in a simple HTML page. Upon pressing a button,  the news API should return a list of results. I would like to print the response to the console.

The request looks like that: (But they do not provide a complete HTML example)

```
const url ="https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/NewsSearchAPI?autoCorrect=false&pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&q=Taylor+Swift&safeSearch=false"
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "XXXXXXXX"
  },
}

fetch(url, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

The Rapid API key can be obtained here:  https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/web-search

Would like to have an HTML with a button, and output the results to the console or to a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Here is the ContextualWeb News API request embedded in a simple HTML page. Upon pressing the button, the resulting JSON is written to the console.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin: 40px 40px; width: 450px;">

        <button onclick="makeGETRequest()">Make the News API call</button>

        <p>see console the for results</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        function makeGETRequest() {
            const url = "https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/NewsSearchAPI?autoCorrect=false&pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&q=Taylor+Swift&safeSearch=false"
            const options = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "contextualwebsearch-websearch v1.p.rapidapi.com",
                    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                },
            }

            fetch(url, options)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(e => console.error(e))
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => showResults(data))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))

showResults(data) {
   data.map(news => console.log(news.title));
}
```

Call a function inside the fetch that will deal with the result. If you are using pure JavaScript, you can try innerHTML to write the result.

Comment: Hi Michael, can you take a look at the answer I posted. I warped you answer in an HTML document. Thanks!

Comment: Ow, sorry, I did not understand your question, now I see... just a few warnings: this code is using ES6+ syntax (you have to use Babel to transpile otherwise won't work in IE), fetch API also doesn't work in IE and older browsers, you can use axios library or ajax. Just for you know :)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware to that.